# Where are uploaded files stored?

Tags: document-library, document

Very naive question here: when you upload to SharePoint, are the files stored in the file system or in SQL Server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The files are (generally) stored in SQL server in databases called content databases together with all other content, such as list items and metadata.

Answer (score 9):

They are stored in the Content Database on SQL Server.  There are [provisions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802976.aspx) to offload the files to the file system and [third party tools](http://www.metalogix.com/Products/StoragePoint.aspx) to assist with it.

Answer (score 2):

Files that you upload within SharePoint to Document libraries are normally stored within SQL server.

However, if you're uploading files as part of a Feature that you are developing and installing, those files can be served from the filesystem OR from the database.